# Переключение формы Java FX после событий WebEngine

Tags: java, javafx, oauth

Отлавливаю загрузку нужной страницы и вытаскиваю token из url так:

```
webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Worker.State state, Worker.State newState) {
    if (newState.equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
        //Переключаю форму здесь
    }
}
```

Форму переключаю так:

```
private void showMainView(String sessionID) {
try {
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
    getClass().getResource("mainview.fxml")
  );
  scene.setRoot((Parent) loader.load());
  MainViewController controller = 
    loader.<MainViewController>getController();
  controller.initSessionID(this, sessionID);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(LoginManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}}}
```

Приложение работает, все переключает, но после переключения формы валит исключение:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafx.scene.web.WebView.processMouseEvent(WebView.java:1005)
at javafx.scene.web.WebView.lambda$registerEventHandlers$32(WebView.java:1144)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventQueue.fire(EventQueue.java:48)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.handleEnterExit(Scene.java:3676)
//и так далее
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а лисенер мышовый случайно на вебвью не вешается?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, вообще ничего не вешается. Может проблема в потоках(webengine грузит страницу в своем потоке)?

Comment: Ну так у тебя в стактрейсе написано, где проблема
at javafx.scene.web.WebView.processMouseEvent(WebView.java:1005)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, я кроме webview.getengine() вообще ничего с ним не делаю. Сама логика авторизации правильная?